# How to retrieve value in input checkbox (Using Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is duplicate question to other, however I have problem pertaining why their is no value output in my console.

My Goal: I want to get the value of checkbox.

I have here my codes.

State:

```
employ_status:''
```

Constructor:

```
this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_relocate.bind(this);
```

Handle:

```
handle_employ_status(e){
        console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.name);
    }
```

JSX:

```
<div className="form-check-inline disabled">
    <label className="form-check-label">
        <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        className="form-check-input" 
        name="employmentstatus"
        onChange={this.handle_employ_status} 
        defaultChecked={false} 
        value="Self-Employed"/>Self-Employed
    </label>
</div>
<div className="form-check-inline disabled">
    <label className="form-check-label">
        <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        className="form-check-input" 
        name="employmentstatus" 
        onChange={this.handle_employ_status}
        defaultChecked={false}  
        value="Student"/>Student
    </label>
</div>
```

Console:

```
console.log(this.state.employ_status);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor

```
this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_relocate.bind(this);
```

should be replace with

```
this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_status.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're binding `this` to wrong handler:

```
this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_relocate.bind(this);
```

Should be:

```
this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_status.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You no need to do binding in constructor if you use arrow function

```
handle_employ_status = e => {
    console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.name);
}
```

Also to handle checkbox values you can do something like below

```
 constructor(){
        this.state = {
            empChecked: false,
            stuChecked: true
        }
    }

    handle_employ_status = e = {
        if(e.target.value == "Self-Employed"){
            this.setState({
                empChecked: !this.state.empChecked
            });
        }

        if(e.target.value == "Student"){
            this.setState({
                stuChecked: !this.state.stuChecked
            });
        }
        console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.name);
    }


<div className="form-check-inline disabled">
    <label className="form-check-label">
        <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        className="form-check-input" 
        name="employmentstatus"
        onChange={this.handle_employ_status} 
        defaultChecked={false}
        checked={this.state.empChecked} 
        value="Self-Employed"/>Self-Employed
    </label>
</div>
<div className="form-check-inline disabled">
    <label className="form-check-label">
        <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        className="form-check-input" 
        name="employmentstatus" 
        onChange={this.handle_employ_status}
        defaultChecked={false} 
        checked={this.state.stuChecked}  
        value="Student"/>Student
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some issues in your code:

1. `this.handle_employ_status = this.handle_employ_relocate.bind(this);` In this code, where is `handle_employ_relocate` function?.
2. If you need to use function `handle_employ_relocate` you need change your handle function..
   `handle_employ_status(e){ //should be named by "handle_employ_relocate"
       console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.name);
   }`
3. In your `.jsx` file, if you `Control` your component, you should remove `UnControl` property:
   `defaultChecked={false} //this line should be convert to checked={this.state.employ_status}`